# How do I move an installed package app from one sandbox to another?

Tags: sandbox, installedpackage

I've seen plenty of questions talking about production, but I just made a new sandbox and need to move CalendarAnything (listed under Installed Packages) into the new one. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

If it was installed before you created the sandbox, it should already be there. If not, just go back to [CalendarAnything](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Hn2kEAC) page and install it, choosing "Sandbox" install rather than "Production" install.

Comment: If you want to clone the sandbox I think recently there is a beta testing going on that you can contact Salesforce on cloning a sandbox